# Estilos para un input type email

Tags: css, html5

```css
input[type=text], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-5">
          <input type="text" name="nomdirecto" id="nomdirecto" placeholder="NOMBRE DE CONTACTO DIRECTO" required/>
      </div>
     <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          <input type="email" name="correocli" id="correocli" placeholder="CORREO" required/>
      </div>
```

El problema es que intente copiar la parte del ccs cambiando el text por email y no se aplica el estilo.

Comment: Si lo que estas buscando es igualar el estilo css que tienes en el input[type=text], lo que tienes que hacer es agregar otro selector a tu css: input[type=text], input[type=email],select {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes agregar a tu código css:

```
input[type=text], input[type="email"], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y si quisiera agregar esos estilos a un select como se pondria?

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que el estilo es para entradas de tipo text lo que te falta es definir  que también vas a usar ese estilo en el  **type=email**

```css
input[type=text],input[type=email], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-12 col-md-5">
          <input type="text" name="nomdirecto" id="nomdirecto" placeholder="NOMBRE DE CONTACTO DIRECTO" required/>
      </div>
     <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
          <input type="email" name="correocli" id="correocli" placeholder="CORREO" required/>
      </div>
```